# Chrome Browser Extension Load Dynamic Content From Default Popup Ppage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am struggling how to display dynamic or external content from popup.html in Chrome browser.

My manifest.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "New Extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "My new Chrome extension", 
    "icons": {
        "16": "name.png"
    },
  "options_page": "option.html",
  "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "New Extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },
    "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

Right now my popup.html looks like

```
<html>
<body>
show dynamic/externally loaded content here
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously that is incorrect/incomplete.
What are my options, can I "link through" the dynamic content?  I do not think I want to use IFRAME, but what about AJAX?

How can this be accomplished?

Any help appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hard to tell what your problem really is. Why don't you want to use an iframe to begin with? Have you tried to use AJAX and run into any problems?

Comment: @Xan I just do not know which AJAX code to add.

Comment: @Xan there are many problems or shortcoming with IFRAME.  Not sure if it is wise to get into this here and now.  Sorry I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is, because it's relevant to your case. At least a short statement "I don't want to use `<iframe>` because [reasons]" would be good for the question. I see that you're new, but you need to narrow down your question. There are good tips in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, be sure to look at it.